# Download an part of a multipart upload in amazon s3

Tags: web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, cloud

Is it possible to download one part of a multi-part upload in amazon S3?

that is. I have uploaded say 5 of 10 parts, then i realize that i need to rewrite a part of on of those uploaded parts, can i download that part rewrite what needs to be rewritten and upload again. Or do i need to cache all uploaded parts locally to be able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would like to do is not possible. Once a file has been finalized, its parts can not be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Why you want to download the uploaded part? You can just change the part of the file and re-upload, it will overwrite the part and then you can merge the all parts.